# Python: Push to Heroku "No matching distribution found for facebook-sdk==1.0.0a0"

Tags: python, heroku, pip

I installed the python facebook api using the following command on my local machine:

```
$ pip install http://github.com/pythonforfacebook/facebook-sdk/tarball/master
```

I have it existing as the following version:

```
[..., 'facebook-sdk==1.0.0a0', .. ]
```

I have it listed in my requirements.txt file as:

```
facebook-sdk==1.0.0a0
```

---

Question: How can I get this to work or how can I tell Heroku to find the source for the the version at the URL?